# Possible to automatically create a timestamp record on insert with Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I've just created a Postgres database and table ('users'). My table has a `created_at` column of type:

```
TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL;
```

I basically want to use this column to keep track of when a new user is created. Is there a way to have Postgres automatically update this with each insert or do I have to supply it a value for this on every insert?

(I want to say when using it before with [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/), it created this automatically - so wondering if this was done through Sequelize as a default when inserting).

Thank you!

Comment: You might also want to look at this answer, which talks about how to create a trigger based on update, create, or other events.  These types of triggers can be used to update/create a timestamp when a row is created, or any time it's updated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31147796/postgresql-trigger-update-timestamp-on-field-update

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I automatically update a timestamp in PostgreSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556474/how-do-i-automatically-update-a-timestamp-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 20):

You can declare a timestamp field to automatically be filled with the current time on INSERT by including the `DEFAULT now()` clause in your column definition.