# Updating timestamp when a field is edited in pg admin

Tags: postgresql

I am modifying data directly in pg admin 4, where I have to validate manually by marking a boolean value to true that is false by default.

[image]

I want that when I modify the value in that column, the updated_at column value should also be updated to current timestamp so I can query data with modified date.
How do I achieve this?

Comment: You need a trigger for that, see e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31147796

Comment: Really appreciate for quickest and valid solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The post desired behavior is more simple than code demo in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html.

setup:

```
CREATE temp TABLE test (
    misc int,
    is_valid boolean,
    updated_at timestamptz
);

INSERT INTO test (misc, is_valid)
    VALUES (1, FALSE);

CREATE FUNCTION update_test_update_at() RETURNS trigger AS $func$
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.* != OLD.* THEN NEW.updated_at := current_timestamp;
        END IF;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_last_edit
    BEFORE UPDATE OF is_valid ON test
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE FUNCTION update_test_update_at();
```

test:

```
UPDATE
    test
SET
    is_valid = true
RETURNING
    *;
```

Comment: To filter out changes that don't actually change values do `IF NEW.* != OLD.* THEN NEW.updated_at := current_timestamp; ... END IF;`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver yes. you are right...